# Plugin para ordenar imagens numa matriz

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou à procura de um plugin em javascript ou jQuery que me permita ter uma tabela de imagens (por exemplo, 6 x 6) e através de drag 'n' drop ou apenas cliques, me possibilite o reposicionamento entre elas. Já procurei com todos os termos de pesquisa que me lembrei e não encontrei nada semelhante.

Ou seja, se numa matriz de 6 x 6 eu clicar ou arrastar na imagem número 1 (na posição 1 x 1) até à imagem número 29 (posição 5 x 4 ) elas trocam entre si. Passando a 29 a ficar no lugar da 1 e vice-versa.

Alguém conhece algum plugin que explora essa solução?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei dois *plugins* que fazem isso que você quer:

1. [**Jquery Shapeshift**](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift)

   > Shapeshift é um plugin que irá organizar dinamicamente uma coleção de
   >   elementos em um sistema de grade e coluna similar ao Pinterest. O que o
   >   diferencia é a capacidade de arrastar e soltar itens dentro da grade,
   >   mantendo uma posição de índice lógico para cada item.

   <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/)</kbd>
2. [**jQuery Gridly**](https://github.com/ksylvest/jquery-gridly)

   > Gridly é um plugin jQuery para permitir arrastar e soltar, bem como o redimensionamento em grades.

   <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/)</kbd>